# Is it possible to query a query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I come from a ColdFusion background where we made FREQUENT usage of Query of Queries to speed up our page.  I have a query now that brings in a ton of data of all the departments for all of the sites, and on the main page I want to display the information like so:

```
Site 001
   -  Dept 01
   -  Dept 02
   -  Dept 03
Site 002
   -  Dept 01
   -  Dept 02
etc.
```

Normally, I would query all the unique sites in my master query by assigning the master query to a variable, this hits the DB one time.  Then, I'd do a query of queries to query that variable to get the unique sites, then in a foreach loop query that same variable to get the departments for the site.

As far as I can tell in Entity Framework each of my foreach queries is actually going out and querying the DB again from scratch.  Is there no way to reuse data you've already pulled down in EF Core?  I'm working with 100k+ row databases, and while they've got keys and are relatively quick, querying it 900 times on one page load is ridiculous.

Comment: If you do a `ToList` then that will pull the data into memory to be reused and you can then run Linq-To-Object queries on it.  Alternatively if you create a EF query that pulls a lot of data then do a further query on that then the actual SQL should be more efficient than pulling a bunch of data to just further filter on, but it's a trade off on which strategy would work best for you.

Comment: The simple solution is to materialize the query first as above comments describes. However your question does not sound like you are making use of [joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-expression-syntax-examples-join-operators).

Comment: It also depends on how OP is using EF and navigation properties, eager/lazy loading. Theoretically, there would be no need for looping over the sites to get the data for each department. EF can do that in one go (it depends on how you build the query how many trips it makes). But maybe you are going ahead of yourself?. Do you need to load all of this data up-front? Can you use some sort of lazy loading in your UI? Meaning, only load the departments if the user is interested? Also, would be nice to show us your EF models.

Comment: Linq to Object might be exactly what I was looking for, I just didn't know what it was called in this world.  I'm joining 3 tables (2 of them twice) and getting a full list of every single site, and every single department all in one query.  So it's :
Site 0001 - Dept 01
Site 0001 - Dept 02
Site 0001 - Dept 03

Etc.

Hopefully I can make it work this way!

Comment: Show us how you created your models, so we can see how to better project the query.